# Adding text on plot depending on axes limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, plot

So I have this following plot

[image]

Which comes from this code

```
for j in range(a.shape[1] // 2):
z = np.polyfit(a[:, 2* j], a[:, 2 * j + 1], 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
e[j]=z[0]
plt.plot(a[:, 2* j],p(a[:, 2* j]))
g.show()
```

The code might seem complicated but thats not the problem here. The problem is the text inside the plot. I have written the text using annotations

```
plt.annotate('Mean stiffness k', xy=(3,7),fontsize=8, fontweight='semibold',    fontstyle='italic')    
plt.annotate(Stiffness, xy=(6,7))   
plt.annotate('N/m', xy=(7.5,7))
plt.annotate('Mean modulus E', xy=(3,6.5),fontsize=8, fontweight='semibold', fontstyle='italic')    
plt.annotate(Emodulus, xy=(5.9,6.5))   
plt.annotate('N/m^2', xy=(8.9,6.5))
```

And whats annoying me is that every time I have different set of data, where the y and x-values of the plot increases/decreases, I have to adjust all of the above annotations! Rather I would like if i somehow could make my text fixed so its linked and ALWAYS on the top left corner.

Hope somebody can help me!

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation in your first code sample. If you would use it like that it would give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

You're using annotate in a rather unusual way. As the name suggests, it's meant to be used to annotate data points, so by default it uses data coordinates as input.
This however can be changed. For a complete overview, refer to [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate).

Here the idea would be to specify the coordinates in "axes fraction". That is, the lower left corner of the axes corresponds to (0,0) and the top right one to (1,1). To specify axes coordinates in annotate use the additional `xycoords="axes fraction"` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([8,154,66])
plt.annotate('Mean stiffness k', xy=(.3,.7), xycoords="axes fraction") 
plt.show()
```